# JSP Bean set property of enum type resorting to String

Tags: java, jsp, enums

I have created bean counterparts to some of my enum types for use in a JSP page. Originally, I had to cycle through all possible enum values via string comparison when I set the enum bean to a particular value, but I just learned that you can actually just set the type to match the native enum type and JSP handles the string matching by itself like the code below shows.

**Original set property:**

```
  public void setName(String name)
  {
    switch(name)
    {
      case "NONE":
        this.causeOfDisconnect = CauseOfDisconnect.NONE;
        break;
      case "EXCLUSIVE_SESSION":
        this.causeOfDisconnect = CauseOfDisconnect.EXCLUSIVE_SESSION;
        break;
      case "SESSION_TIMED_OUT":
        this.causeOfDisconnect = CauseOfDisconnect.SESSION_TIMED_OUT;
        break;
      case "INVALID_CAUSE_OF_DISCONNECT":
        this.causeOfDisconnect = CauseOfDisconnect.INVALID_CAUSE_OF_DISCONNECT;
        break;
    }
  }
```

**New set property:**

```
  public void setName(CauseOfDisconnect name)
  {
    this.causeOfDisconnect = name;
  }
```

**Enum type definition:**

```
public enum CauseOfDisconnect
{
  NONE(0),
  EXCLUSIVE_SESSION(1),
  SESSION_TIMED_OUT(2),
  INVALID_CAUSE_OF_DISCONNECT(3);

  private final int code;

  private CauseOfDisconnect(int code)
  {
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

**Use in JSP:**

```
<jsp:useBean id="exclusiveSessionDisconnect" class="sessionmanager.CauseOfDisconnectBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="exclusiveSessionDisconnect" property="name" value="EXCLUSIVE_SESSION" />
```

The above code works fine for that enum type (which has an integer internal value), but when I apply the same "fix" to another enum type which has a String internal value, the server returns this error: Can't find a method to write property 'name' of type 'java.lang.String' in a bean of type.

**Error in this type of bean:**

```
<jsp:useBean id="userIdCookie" class="sessionmanager.CookiesBean" />
<jsp:setProperty name="userIdCookie" property="name" value="USER_ID" />
```

I have searched for a similar question and this person seems to be having the same problem, but I do not understand his answer.

Similar problem: [enums are being interpreted as Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217285/enums-are-being-interpreted-as-strings)

Any ideas on how to make this work?

---

**Update**

After much review of code, I've finally figured out what is causing the error.  In some of my bean classes, I only have a set method defined.  Those bean classes worked for the changes (fix) I made above.  But for some others, I also had a get method defined that returned a string.  Since I changed the type parameter for the set method to the enum type, it conflicted with the return type of the get method.  It seems that for beans, you need to have the same types for get input and set return variables.

Like so:

```
public void setName(String name)
```

must have corresponding getter (and vice-versa)

```
public String getName()
```

Comment: I've confirmed that if I apply the new method to all other enum types in my source that has integer constant values, it works fine.  I've applied it to more than 2 enum types already.  But for those enums with String constant values, it outputs the error.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the internal interpretation of Enum in JSP but in Enums out of the box you have the valueOf method

```
   enum Test{
        AAAA
   }

   Test.valueOf("AAAA")
```

that can replace your `setName` method.

As for supported values take a look at :  http://www.it.cas.cz/manual/jsp/syntaxref1216.html#17460

Object target is converted into a String, so this is not supported and you need to have a method that accepts string

```
...
Short or Short

java.lang.Short.valueOf(String)

Object

new String(string-literal)
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do.  I'll try that `valueOf` replacement within the setName method.

Comment: but the signature of setName should be setName(String name)

Comment: Yes, I just have to handle IllegalArgumentException where there's no corresponding enum type.  But it's not a big problem.

Comment: Nope, I just created a different setter method that didn't clash with an existing getter method return type.  Your suggestion is nice but jstl bean already has builtin `.valueOf` mechanic in the `setProperty` tag

Answer (score 0):

Its looking for method with signature `setName(String)`, which is removed.
I doubt that solution is working, try cleaning your app/web server's workspace and restart.

Then it will start failing consistently.

Comment: No, it works for the bean enum type mentioned above, but it fails for other bean enum types that I applied the same changes. I edited my problem for clarity.